# After setState render is not calling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large set of data that I'm retrieving from an API.

For this I have added a promise. As API taking too much time to fetch the data I am trying to display the loader. Here is my sample

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import ApplicationService from '../services/applicationServices';
import renderIf from 'render-if';
import OverlayLoader from '../../common/components/overlayLoader';

class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoader : false
    };
  };

  onTapNext = () => {
    this.setState({isLoader: true});
    ApplicationService.getPersonalDetails(AppService.personaDetails).then(function(resp) {
        // Code for fetching data and do some sorting
        // hide loader once get the result 
        this.setState({isLoader: false});
    }, function(error) {
      this.setState({isLoader: false});
    });
  }

  render() {
    var _component = "";
        if(this.state.isLoader){
             _component = <OverlayLoader></OverlayLoader>;
        } else {
            _component = <Button className="footerButtons" onClick={this.onTapNext}>FETCH DATA</Button>;
        }
    return (
        <div> {_component}</div>    
    )
    }
}

export default SampleComponent;
```

But when the promise get called I am not able to see the Loader. I am using **OverlayLoader** component for showing the loader.

Can anyone let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: maybe your `getPersonalDetails` fails real fast and thus `this.setState({isLoader: false})` in your onRejected is called immediately after your `this.setState({isLoader: true});` in `onTapNext`

Comment: @AnisSmail I checked the API call and they are working as expected. It is also taking around 2-3 seconds for completion.

Answer (score 0):

I think state is not changing, Try this code for onTapNext method

```
onTapNext = () => {
this.setState({isLoader: true});
const self = this;
ApplicationService.getPersonalDetails(AppService.personaDetails).then(function(resp) {
    // Code for fetching data and do some sorting
    // hide loader once get the result 
    self.setState({isLoader: false});
}, function(error) {
  self.setState({isLoader: false});
});
```

}

Comment: Checked your solution but getting the same issue.

Comment: Or maybe try if this would work `.then( resp => { // Code for fetching
// hide loader
this.setState({isLoader: false})`

Answer (score 0):

you set the state first and then you call the api., in your code both are **executing concurrently** so that loader not populating, first set the loader state and in callback of setState call the api.   you could refer bellow code

```
onTapNext = () => {
    this.setState({isLoader: true}, this.onCallback());
}

onCallback = () => {

    const self = this;
        ApplicationService.getPersonalDetails(AppService.personaDetails).then(function(resp) {
        // Code for fetching data and do some sorting
        // hide loader once get the result 
        self.setState({isLoader: false});
    }, function(error) {
    self.setState({isLoader: false});
    });

}
```

Comment: I tried yours solution also but getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this, the loader is displayed directly and only when your promise is resolved in the last then will your loader disappear

```
   this.state = {
      isLoader : true
    };


onTapNext = () => {
    this.setState({isLoader: true});
    ApplicationService.getPersonalDetails(AppService.personaDetails).then( resp => {
        // Code for fetching data and do some sorting
        // hide loader once get the result 

    }).then(
      this.setState({isLoader: false});
    );
  }
```

Also API call should probably be made in the componentDidMount() function (a call of mine) unless you really need it onClick

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    })
    fetch('/api/data')
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(datas =>
            this.setState(
                {datas, loading: false}
            )
        ).catch(err => this.setState({
            APIerror: true,
            APIerrorMessage: err
        }))
}
```